# Как соединить несколько точек прямой и добавить подписи для каждой точки

Tags: python, matplotlib

Есть 3 координаты

```
[1,2] P
[3,4] Q 
[-3,-2] R
```

Как нарисовать прямую через три точки, и чтобы аннотации были у каждой координаты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вот такая например для точки P

Comment: для того чтобы суметь провести прямую через три точки - все они должны лежать на одной прямой - в вопросе вы привели точки которые __не принадлежат__ одной прямой) Может вы имеете ввиду ломаную линию, а не прямую? В этом случае отредактируйте пожалуйста вопрос

Comment: @MaxU ссори, исправил)

Answer (score 1):

Принципиально, это можно сделать так:

```
P = [1,2] 
Q = [3,4] 
R = [-3,-2]
coords = list(zip(P, Q, R))

plt.ylim(-4, 6)
plt.xlim(-4, 6)
plt.plot(coords[0], coords[1], marker='o', markersize=35, markerfacecolor='orange', markeredgecolor='orange')

plt.annotate('P', (coords[0][0]-.15, coords[1][0]-.2), size=15)
plt.annotate('Q', (coords[0][1]-.15, coords[1][1]-.2), size=15)
plt.annotate('R', (coords[0][2]-.15, coords[1][2]-.2), size=15)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, советую оптимизировать данные так, чтобы аннотации можно было писать циклом автоматически вне зависимости от количества данных. 
Разумеется, с позиционированием аннотаций надо будет попадать.